# Add 'Done' and 'New line' buttons on keyboard in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, programmatically-created

I have created a window based application with a `UITabbarController` as the `RootViewController`.
In one of the tabs, i have provided `UITextField` and `UITextView`.
I want to provide two buttons on the keyboard itself:

- Done - which will hide the keyboard.
- Enter - for new line.

Please post your answer if anybody has some idea how to do it.

Comment: You can add these two buttons on a tool bar and by animation put that on top of keyboard.

Comment: Keyboard having return key for new line for textView and for textfield you will not need any new line as well.

Answer (score 4):

For the UITextField you can change the return key to a done key by setting the following:

```
targetTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

However, you won't be able to have a Enter and Done key at the same time without custom addition of views to the keyboard.

Also, to control the done behavior of the keyboard you have to implement a UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
targetTextField.delegate = self;
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
     return YES;  //dismisses the keyboard
}
```

I know you can set the returnKeyType for a UITextView but I'm not sure if you can manipulate the return key behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You have a tutorial on how add subviews to the iPhone keyboard here :

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-custimize-keyboard.html

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Answer (score 1):

For some reason return YES;  didn't work on its own. that worked for me :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyNext) {
        NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
        // Try to find next responder
        UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
        if (nextResponder) {
            // Found next responder, so set it.
            [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }

    if (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyDone) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;  //dismisses the keyboard
}
```